# Deinterlace filter in directshow applications

Tags: c++, windows, filter, linker, directshow

I am trying to capture video from a capture card and display the feed in a window with deinterlacing.

I am using Dscaler's Deinterlace filter (http://deinterlace.sourceforge.net/Filter.htm). I registered the filter (Deinterlace.ax) via

```
regsvr32.exe Deinterlace.ax
```

I then tried to modify "playcap" from Microsoft's Directshow samples. I took the source code for Deinterlace and copied "Deinterlace.h" (which contains the definition of the filter) and placed it in the project.

In the CaptureVideo function, I tried to QueryInterface the filter.

```
CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pDeinterlace;
hr = g_pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IDeinterlace, (LPVOID *) &pDeinterlace);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return hr;
}
```

When compiling, I get a linking error:

```
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDeinterlace
```

These are my includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <dshow.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <streams.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Deinterlace.h"
```

For the libraries and directories, I just included Directshow. Without the Deinterlace filter code, the program compiles fine.

I am not sure how to correctly include the filter (since there are no tutorials I can find on this). I am not sure where I am suppose to put the Deinterlace.ax file (or rename it to Deinterlace.dll?).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Above was solved by Roman R to add Deinterlace_i.c to the project.

I have another question. I am kind of new to Directshow and I understand the fundamentals, but I cannot successfully query the interface, and attach the deinterlacing filter to the rest of the graph.

Ideally, I would like:

```
Source Capture (preview) -> Deinterlace Filter -> Video Render
```

I have tried to query the interface from the graph but I have no luck, it will fail:

```
hr = g_pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IDeinterlace, (LPVOID*) &g_pDeinterlace);
if(FAILED(hr)) {    // Fails here
    Msg(TEXT("Failed"));
    return hr;
}

hr = g_pGraph->AddFilter((IBaseFilter*)g_pDeinterlace, L"Deinterlace");
if(FAILED(hr)) {
    Msg(TEXT("Failed in adding filter"));
    return hr;
}

g_pDeinterlace->put_IsOddFieldFirst(VARIANT_FALSE);
```

Somehow, I need it to connect pins from the source

```
// somehow pSrcFilter connects to pDeinterlace

hr = g_pCapture->RenderStream (&PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
            g_pDeinterlace, NULL, NULL);
```

I can get the entire thing working in GraphEdit, but writing the code is c

Comment: Including `Deinterlace.h` is insufficient. Include additionally `Deinterlace_i.c` - another file produced out of deinterlacer's IDL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Including Deinterlace.h is insufficient. Include additionally Deinterlace_i.c - another file produced out of deinterlacer's IDL
2. DScaler won't connect to `Preview` output pin. It needs time stamps on the media samples (frames) and only `Capture` pin have them available. User capture output leg, not preview.

DScaler code:

```
HRESULT CDeinterlaceFilter::Deinterlace(IMediaSample* pSource)
{
    CAutoLock l(&m_DeinterlaceLock);
    // ...
    // Get the input stream times
    if(FAILED(pSource->GetTime(&rtStart,&rtStop)))
    {
        return E_FAIL;
```

Comment: I was able to connect the preview pin from Graphedit, so it is different that coding it doesnt work?

Comment: You should be able to connect in code as well, but it won't run without time stamps anyway.